# How does probability come in to play in a kNN algorithm?

Tags: scikit-learn, probability, knn, nearest-neighbor

kNN seems relatively simple to understand: you have your data points and you draw them in your feature space (in a feature space of dimension 2, its the same as drawing points on a xy plane graph). When you want to classify a new data, you put the new data onto the same feature space, find the nearest k neighbors, and see what their labels are, ultimately taking the label(s) with highest votes.

So where does probability come in to play here? All I am doing to calculating distance between two points and taking the label(s) of the closest neighbor.

Answer (score 0):

For a new test sample you look on the K nearest neighbors and look on their labels. 
You count how many of those K samples you have in each of the classes, and divide the counts by the number of classes.

For example - lets say that you have 2 classes in your classifier and you use K=3 nearest neighbors, and the labels of those 3 nearest samples are (0,1,1) - the probability of class 0 is 1/3 and the probability for class 1 is 2/3.

Comment: How does this apply to multilabel classification?

Comment: Multi label or multi class?

Comment: Multi class means that you have a few classes (more than 2). Multi label means that you have a few labels and for each of them you can have 2 or more classes (for example predicting the age and the gender of customers).

Comment: I meant multilabel. How does posterior probability work for multilabel?

Comment: You can do the same for each of the labels... take the K closest samples, check their labels and calculate the probabilities by those neighbors